# Как подключить javascript в functions.php в wordpress'е

Tags: javascript, wordpress

У меня есть html, css и javascript коды с codepen'а , [вот этот pen](http://codepen.io/EngCode/pen/PPJQER). Html и css встали нормально, а вот с js никак не получается

Вот сам javascript код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".Modern-Slider").slick({
     autoplay:true,
     autoplaySpeed:10000,
     speed:600,
     slidesToShow:1,
     slidesToScroll:1,
     pauseOnHover:false,
     dots:true,
     pauseOnDotsHover:true,
     cssEase:'linear',
  // fade:true,
     draggable:false,
     prevArrow:'<button class="PrevArrow"></button>',
     nextArrow:'<button class="NextArrow"></button>', 
  });

})
```

Если просто добавить его в functions.php, то выдает ошибку:
***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'***

Может знаете, как подключить этот код?

Comment: @pepel_xD   я пробовал прописывать wp_enqueue_script и создавал отдельно slider.js с кодом внутри, но не помогло.  Вот и решил сюда писать, как последний вариант

Comment: почему вы считаете, что вам нужно подключить этот скрипт именно через `functions.php`? В какой части сайта, на какой странице планируется его использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если стоит задача выполнить произвольный текст скрипта указанного в functions.php
то можно поставить хук на нужную функцию и применить такой прием:

```
add_action('the_post','my_custom_text_script');
function my_custom_text_script()
{ ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $(".Modern-Slider").slick({
     autoplay:true,
     autoplaySpeed:10000,
     speed:600,
     slidesToShow:1,
     slidesToScroll:1,
     pauseOnHover:false,
     dots:true,
     pauseOnDotsHover:true,
     cssEase:'linear',
  // fade:true,
     draggable:false,
     prevArrow:'<button class="PrevArrow"></button>',
     nextArrow:'<button class="NextArrow"></button>', 
  });
});
</script>
<?php }
```